# How can i Flatten this JSON file so that i can make it compatible to be uploaded to SQL

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am having a Nested JSON file, How can I flatten it so that I can make it compatible to upload it in SQL. This JSON file is nested and till the "in_network" key it works fine but the value "in_network" has a list of dicts so I guess my code cannot determine how to perform the task after that. I might be missing some lines of code. A help in code will be very much helpful.

```
{
  "reporting_entity_name": "medicare",
  "reporting_entity_type": "medicare",
  "plan_name": "medicaid",
  "plan_id_type": "hios",
  "plan_id": "1111111111",
  "plan_market_type": "individual",
  "last_updated_on": "2020-08-27",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "in_network": [
    {
      "negotiation_arrangement": "ffs",
      "name": "Knee Replacement",
      "billing_code_type": "CPT",
      "billing_code_type_version": "2020",
      "billing_code": "27447",
      "description": "Arthroplasty, knee condyle and plateau, medial and lateral compartments",
      "negotiated_rates": [
        {
          "provider_groups": [
            {
              "npi": [0],
              "tin": {
                "type": "ein",
                "value": "11-1111111"
              }
            }
          ],
          "negotiated_prices": [
            {
              "negotiated_type": "negotiated",
              "negotiated_rate": 123.45,
              "expiration_date": "2022-01-01",
              "billing_class": "institutional"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the python code I am using.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('new_test.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())

nested_data = pd.json_normalize(data, max_level=10)
```

After the current code the dataframe looks like
[image]

What ever is inside in_network is stored as it is but I want to store it like in_network.negotiation_arrangement a new column with value or in_network.name with its value.
Something like every key has its own column.

Here is what the table

```
    reporting_entity_name   reporting_entity_type   plan_name   plan_id_type    plan_id plan_market_type    last_updated_on version in_network
0   medicare    medicare    medicaid    hios    1111111111  individual  2020-08-27  1.0.0   [{'negotiation_arrangement': 'ffs', 'name': 'Knee Replacement', 'billing_code_type': 'CPT', 'billing_code_type_version': '2020', 'billing_code': '27447', 'description': 'Arthroplasty, knee condyle and plateau, medial and lateral compartments', 'negotiated_rates': [{'provider_groups': [{'npi': [0], 'tin': {'type': 'ein', 'value': '11-1111111'}}], 'negotiated_prices': [{'negotiated_type': 'negotiated', 'negotiated_rate': 123.45, 'expiration_date': '2022-01-01', 'billing_class': 'institutional'}]}]}]
```

Comment: I have edited and added in the question the table in code format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to parse and [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) to merge:

```
from functools import reduce

import pandas as pd


df_main = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data,
    meta=["reporting_entity_name", "reporting_entity_type", "plan_name", "plan_id_type",
          "plan_id", "plan_market_type", "last_updated_on", "version"],
    record_path=["in_network"]
).drop(columns="negotiated_rates")

df_provider = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data,
    meta=["reporting_entity_name", "reporting_entity_type", "plan_name", "plan_id_type",
          "plan_id", "plan_market_type", "last_updated_on", "version"],
    record_path=["in_network", "negotiated_rates", "provider_groups"]
)

df_prices = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data,
    meta=["reporting_entity_name", "reporting_entity_type", "plan_name", "plan_id_type",
          "plan_id", "plan_market_type", "last_updated_on", "version"],
    record_path=["in_network", "negotiated_rates", "negotiated_prices"]
)


dfs = [df_main, df_provider, df_prices]
final_df = reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(
    left,
    right,
    on=["reporting_entity_name", "reporting_entity_type", "plan_name", "plan_id_type",
        "plan_id", "plan_market_type", "last_updated_on", "version"]
), dfs).explode("npi")

print(final_df)
```

Output:

```
  negotiation_arrangement              name billing_code_type billing_code_type_version billing_code                                                              description reporting_entity_name reporting_entity_type plan_name plan_id_type     plan_id plan_market_type last_updated_on version npi tin.type   tin.value negotiated_type  negotiated_rate expiration_date  billing_class
0                     ffs  Knee Replacement               CPT                      2020        27447  Arthroplasty, knee condyle and plateau, medial and lateral compartments              medicare              medicare  medicaid         hios  1111111111       individual      2020-08-27   1.0.0   0      ein  11-1111111      negotiated           123.45      2022-01-01  institutional
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, But i have a question as this JSON data is part of huge JSON file. Can there be any other method where I can automate this process without hardcoding the column values.

Comment: Yeah just an example of how normailze works. TBH you dont need df_main and it would be best to join on some sort of unique id.

Comment: With a unique id it's kind of vague for me can you please provide any resources I can follow this JSON data is just a part of huge JSON data so hardcoding every dictionary key gonna take forever.

Comment: I just mean like a billing id or patient id something thats unique